# Sending Video Stream from Front-end(angularjs) to Backend(Django)

Tags: python, django, aiortc

I want to pass video frame from Front-end(`angularjs`) to Back-end(`Django`) for video sreaming. for that I had followed below link. https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/tree/master/examples/server

For Django, I had used `Django-celery` Tasks for `asynchronuos` function. I tried to pass `RtcPeerConnection` object(as arguement) into `celery` task that time I got below error

> **TypeError: Object of type RTCPeerConnection is not JSON serializable**
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/loksun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py",
>   line 50, in _reraise_errors
>       yield   File "/home/loksun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py",
>   line 221, in dumps
>       payload = encoder(data)   File "/home/loksun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py",
>   line 70, in dumps
>       **dict(default_kwargs, **kwargs))   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/**init**.py", line 399, in
>   dumps
>       **kw).encode(obj)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 291, in
>   encode
>       chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 373, in
>   iterencode
>       return _iterencode(o, 0)   File "/home/loksun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py",
>   line 59, in default
>       return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(o)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 268, in
>   default
>       o.**class**.**name**) TypeError: Object of type RTCPeerConnection is not JSON serializable

Any hint will be appreciated. Thank you!